# How create a remote glassfish server

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, glassfish-3, eclipse-indigo, server-administration

Hi folks I want to create a remote glassfish server.I mean to say that I want glassfish server on a single machine and its remote client connect to it and use it and compile/develop their code from that server machine because i don't want to install glassfish on all machines.
My remote users will use eclipse for development
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install glassfish on the machine that you are using. See how it is done with glassfish v2.1: http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/v2.1.1-final.html

Then you need to attach the remote glassfish to your IDE. If you are using the glassfish for development do not forget to enable debug and start glassfish in debug mode.

I have used remote glassfish with IntelliJ, it has a perfect integration. I do not how it will work with Eclipse, but this link: http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat might be what you need.